# stepping into condition even if sring is not same

Tags: string, vb.net, if-statement, equals

I am a beginner in VB.NET. I am looping through a List of Vehicules and add indexes in STRING to another List if the numbers as Strings fit few conditions.

The first condition;  If Not item.Equals("11652") still get into condition even if is not true;

Equals(), Not Equals(), Tostring.Equals

```
Dim cpti = 0

For Each item In Vehicules.Items
    If ex = 1 Then
        If Not item.Equals("11652") Or item.ToString() <> "11785" Or item.ToString() <> "11814" Or item.ToString() <> "11852" Or item.ToString() <> "11853" Then
            list.Add(cpti)
        End If             

        If item.ToString() = "530011" Or item.ToString() = "530012" Or item.ToString() = "530013" Or item.ToString() = "530014" Or item.ToString() = "530015" Or item.ToString() = "530016" Or item.ToString() = "530017" Or item.ToString() = "530018" Or item.ToString() = "530019" Or item.ToString() = "530020" Then
            list.Add(cpti)
        End If  
    ElseIf ex = 3 Then
        If item.ToString() <> "326481" Or item.ToString() <> "326483" Or item.ToString() <> "326556" Or item.ToString() <> "326557" Then
            list.Add(cpti)
        End If
    Else
        liste.Add(cpti)
    End If

    cpti = cpti + 1
Next
```

Comment: Your `If` statements don't make sense.  If you compare the same value multiple times with `Or` operators in between then you will always match everything because one value can't equal two different things at the same time.  For instance, if you use `If x <> "A" Or x <> "B" Or x <> "C" Then` then you will any and every value of `x` because if it's "A" then it won't be "B" or "C" and if it's "B" then it won't be "A" or "C" and so on.  You need to put some thought into the logic first, then write code to implement reasonable logic once you have it.

Comment: thanks a lot, gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take this line

```
If item <> "11652" Or item <> "11785" Then
```

This will always equal true. Let try some example

```
item = "1"
If item <> "11652" Or item <> "11785" Then
If True Or True Then ' Both of them are True, go in the If

item = "11652"
If item <> "11652" Or item <> "11785" Then
If False Or True Then ' One of them is true, go in the If

item = "11785"
If item <> "11652" Or item <> "11785" Then
If True Or False Then ' One of them is true, go in the If
```

You might want to do AND instead of OR. But I don't know the logic behind what you want to do so I can't give you a direct answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for quick reply, the logic is to add item IF it isn't this # or this #, or this or this.

Comment: @Mr1000lb ah! then you need <> and AND. Or even better, put all your numbers in a list then check Not badNumberList.Contains(item)